# Hat Goethe des »Pudels Kern« erfunden oder hat er nur einer älteren Form zur Durchsetzung verholfen?

Tags: etymology, phrase

Die Redewendung »etwas ist des Pudels Kern« im Sinne von »das steckt also wirklich dahinter« ist weithin bekannt und wird oft (z. B. [Wiktionary](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_gefl%C3%BCgelter_Worte/D#Das_also_war_des_Pudels_Kern) oder [diese Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/1694)) auf Goethes *Faust* zurückgeführt. Darin trifft der Protagonist auf einen Pudel, den er mit nach Hause nimmt. Nachdem der Hund die Schwelle übertreten hat, verwandelt er sich in Mephistopheles, den Teufel – die zweite Hauptfigur des Werks. Faust ruft aus:

> Das also war des Pudels Kern.

Nun habe ich heute ein [Video des Blogs *Belles Lettres*](http://www.belleslettres.eu/content/schrift/buchstabe-q-kentum-satem.php) angeschaut, dessen Thema nichts mit Pudeln und deren Kernen zu tun hat. Dennoch ist der Schlusssatz des Videos folgender:

> Das ist des Pudels Kern. Das hat übrigens nicht mit dem Hund, Pudel, zu tun, sondern ist ein altes deutsches Wort für *Rätsel.*

Die Art und Weise wie der Sprecher diesen Satz vorträgt, lässt mich vermuten, dass »des Pudels Kern« als Ausdruck wesentlich älter ist als der erste Teil der Goethe’schen Tragödie. Leider endet das Video bevor das Rätsel gelöst wird, es macht mich dennoch neugierig.

Gilt Goethe wirklich unzweifelhaft als Erfinder des Kerns des Pudels oder war die Figur in vergleichbarer Form bereits zu seiner Zeit mehr oder weniger bekannt, und er hat ihr lediglich zur Durchsetzung verholfen? War vielleicht auch nur das Wort *Pudel* synonym zu Rätsel und sein Kern des Rätsels Lösung?

Comment: Laut dem [Deutschen Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GP08190#XGP08190) hat(te) "Pudel" in verschiedenen Gegenden unterschiedliche Bedeutungen, von der Hunderasse über einen Fehlwurf beim Kegeln bis zur Kaufmannstheke. Teilweise ist das Substantiv maskulin, teils feminin. Von einem Rätsel ist dort allerdings keine Rede, und auch sonst finde ich für den Ausdruck nur Referenzen zu Goethe. Ich würde daher die Aussage in dem Video in Zweifel ziehen.

Comment: Bei *Belles Lettres* erscheint mir öfters die Sicherheit des Vortrags von Thesen größer als die unterliegende Fundiertheit. Ich sehe dort zu oft offensichtliche Vermutungen, die einfach als Fakten in den Raum gestellt werden. Der *Pudel* selbst ist mit ziemlicher Sicherheit aus dem selben Wortstamm entstanden wie das englische *puddle* (Pfütze) - Der Pudel ist originär ein "Wasserhund". Nachdem's im *Faust* um einen "richtigen" Pudel geht, sehe ich keinen Grund, hier von einem nicht mit Fakten untermauerten "Rätsel" - für das ich auch keine Hinweise finden kann - zu sprechen.

Comment: Übrigens hat's der Pudels Kern auch ins Schwedische geschafft - als *pudelns kärna* - und auch mein schwedisches Lexikon führt es (nur) auf den *Faust* zurück.

Comment: @tofro Wie sollte man bei Belles Lettres zu diesem Schluss kommen, wenn man nicht irgendeine Art von etymologischer Quelle dafür hätte? Es würde außerdem sehr für die Stelle im Faust sprechen, weil Goethe dann eben nicht banal auf das wahren Wesen dieses Hundes verweist, sondern doppeldeutig ein Wortspiel aus des Pudels Kern macht.

Comment: Würdest du das Video bitte verlinken? Ich glaube, die Rede war von einem alten niederdeutschen Wort. Vielleicht täusche ich mich aber auch.

Comment: @deponensvogel Der Link, der sich hinter den Wörtern *Belles Lettres* verbirgt, bringt dich bereits dorthin. Allerdings sehe ich, dass es potenziell missverständlich ist; deswegen verlängere ich den Linktext mal eben ;)

Answer (score 6):

Die Aussage

> Das hat übrigens nicht mit dem Hund, Pudel, zu tun.

ist definitiv falsch. Der Pudel, um dessen Kern es geht, ist in Goethes Faust ganz ausdrücklich ein echter schwarzer Hund. Und der Kern, der im Pudel steckte, ist Mephistopheles, also der Teufel:

---

### Faust. Eine Tragödie.

(oft auch als »**Faust. Der Tragödie erster Teil**« oder einfach nur als »**Faust I**« bezeichnet)
von Johann Wolfgang von Goethe

Die Geschichte spielt Anfang des 16. Jahrhunderts, also am Ende des Mittelalters und am Beginn des Zeitalters der Aufklärung. (Der reale Faust lebte von 1480–1538; Goethe hat seine Geschichte nicht erfunden, sondern »nur« die vielen Erzählungen, die sich um die reale Person rankten, zusammengefasst, vielleicht auch erweitert, ganz sicher aber hat er sie literarisch überhöht.)

Der Forscher Heinrich Faust ist ein steter Zweifler und ist mit seinem privaten und beruflichen Leben höchst unzufrieden. In Kapitel 4 will er sich das Leben nehmen, wird aber vom Geläut der Kirchenglocken, die das Osterfest einläuten, davon abgehalten den Giftbecher auszutrinken.

In Kapitel 5 macht Faust dann, gemeinsam mit seinem Famulus Wagner, den berühmten Osterspaziergang.

> *Faust:*
>   Vom Eise befreit sind Strom und Bäche
>   Durch des Frühlings holden, belebenden Blick;
>   Im Tale grünet Hoffnungsglück;
>   Der alte Winter, in seiner Schwäche,
>   Zog sich in rauhe Berge zurück.
>   ...

Bei diesem Spaziergang offenbart der zur Magie neigende Faust dem rationalen Wagner seine innere Zerrissenheit:

> *Faust:*
>   Zwei Seelen wohnen, ach! in meiner Brust,
>   Die eine will sich von der andern trennen;
>   Die eine hält, in derber Liebeslust,
>   Sich an die Welt mit klammernden Organen;
>   Die andre hebt gewaltsam sich vom Dust
>   Zu den Gefilden hoher Ahnen.
>   ...

Faust redet an dieser Stelle auch von Geistern, von denen er sich gerne »*zu neuem, buntem Leben*« entführen lassen würde, doch Wagner warnt vor den Geistern. Er sagt, sie »*lispeln englisch, wenn sie lügen*« (englisch = engelhaft; wie die Engel). Wagner drängt auch darauf, heim zu kehren, weil die Dämmerung schon hereingebrochen ist. In dieser Dämmerung fällt Faust ein schwarzer Hund auf, der den beiden folgt.

Wagner erkennt die Rasse (ein Pudel), und sieht in dem Hund nichts weiter als einen Hund. Doch Faust sieht mehr:

> *Faust:*
>   Bemerkst du, wie in weitem Schneckenkreise
>   Er um uns her und immer näher jagt?
>   Und irr ich nicht, so zieht ein Feuerstrudel
>   Auf seinen Pfaden hinterdrein.

Doch als der schwarze Pudel näher kommt, sieht auch Faust in ihm nichts anderes als einen gewöhnlicher Hund. Faust nimmt ihn mit nach Hause.

Kapitel 6 spielt dann in Fausts Studierzimmer. Faust ist mit dem Pudel allein und sinniert über allerlei Dinge, die ihn bewegen. Dazwischen spricht er immer wieder mit seinem neuen Gesellen:

> *Faust:*
>   Sei ruhig, **Pudel**! renne nicht hin und wider!
>   An der Schwelle was schnoperst du hier?
>   ...
>   Knurre nicht, **Pudel**! Zu den heiligen Tönen,
>   Die jetzt meine ganze Seel umfassen,
>   Will der tierische Laut nicht passen.
>   ...

Faust beschließt, der Bibel auf den Grund zu gehen, und den Originaltext neu ins Deutsche zu übersetzen, denn schon den ersten Satz (»Im Anfang war das Wort«) möchte er anders schrieben (»Im Anfang war der *Sinn*«). Doch wieder wird er vom Pudel gestört. Faust will ihn aus seinem Zimmer hinauswerfen, doch als er den Pudel hinausjagen will, verwandelt sich dieser:

> *Faust:*
>   Soll ich mit dir das Zimmer teilen,
>   Pudel, so laß das Heulen,
>   So laß das Bellen!
>   Solch einen störenden Gesellen
>   Mag ich nicht in der Nähe leiden.
>   Einer von uns beiden
>   Muß die Zelle meiden.
>   Ungern heb ich das Gastrecht auf,
>   Die Tür ist offen, hast freien Lauf.
>   Aber was muß ich sehen!
>   Kann das natürlich geschehen?
>   Ist es Schatten? ist's Wirklichkeit?
>   Wie wird mein Pudel lang und breit!
>   Er hebt sich mit Gewalt,
>   Das ist nicht eines Hundes Gestalt!
>   Welch ein Gespenst bracht ich ins Haus!
>   Schon sieht er wie ein Nilpferd aus,
>   Mit feurigen Augen, schrecklichem Gebiß.
>   Oh! du bist mir gewiß!
>   Für solche halbe Höllenbrut
>   Ist Salomonis Schlüssel gut.

(Mit »Salomonis Schlüssel« ist das nekromantische Zauberbuch »Lemegeton Clavicula Salomoni« gemeint, das Formeln zu Beschwörung von Geistern enthält. Dieses Buch tauchte erstmals im 17. Jahrhundert, also rund 100 Jahre nach dem Tod des realen Faust auf. Zugeschrieben wurde es freilich dem König Salomo, der 2500 Jahre vor Faust lebte. Es darf aber dennoch bezweifelt werden,dass der echte Faust dieses Buch gekannt hat.)

Noch während Faust dieses Buch sucht, sammeln sich auf dem Gang Geister, und raunen einander zu, dass da drinnen einer gefangen ist, den man nicht sitzen lassen sollte, denn er hat den Geistern schon viel Gefallen getan.

Faust beginnt laut Zaubersprüche aus dem Buch zu lesen um die Verwandlung des Pudels aufzuhalten, doch es gelingt ihm nicht. Der Pudel wird immer größer und zerfließt endlich zu Nebel. Als sich der Nebel lichtet, steht Mephistopheles im Gewand eines fahrenden Scholastikus (Studenten) anstelle des Pudels in Fausts Studierzimmer und spricht zu Faust:

> *Mephistopheles:*
>   Wozu der Lärm? was steht dem Herrn zu Diensten?
>
> *Faust:*
>   **Das also war des Pudels Kern!**
>   Ein fahrender Skolast? Der Kasus macht mich lachen.
>
> *Mephistopheles:*
>   Ich salutiere den gelehrten Herrn!
>   Ihr habt mich weidlich schwitzen machen.

---

Dafür, das Goethe den Teufel in Gestalt eines Hundes auftreten lässt, gibt es einen handfesten Grund: Goethe hasste Hunde, und Pudel waren damals eine sehr beliebte Hunderasse, gegen die Goethe eine ganz besondere Abneigung hatte. Also lag es für Goethe nahe, einen Pudel zum Teufel zu machen.

Dazu gibt es auch eine Anekdote:

Goethe leitete das Weimarer Hoftheater, und war ein strenger Direktor. 1803 schrieb er 91 Regeln für Schauspieler, doch Hunde auf der Bühne wollten sich nicht an Goethes strenge Regeln halten. 1812 verfasste Goethe daher die »Erneuerten Anordnungen für das Weimarische Theater«, und in Paragraph 14 dieser Regelsammlung hieß es:

> Kein Hund darf mit auf das Theater gebracht werden.

Und es war auch ausgerechnet ein Pudel, der, wenige Jahre nachdem Faust I veröffentlicht war (das war 1808), Goethe Karriere als Schauspieldirektor beendete:

1814 wurde in Frankreich das Bühnenstück »Der Hund des Aubry oder der Wald von Bondy« uraufgeführt. Darin geht es um einen intelligenten Hund, der einen Mord aufklärt (der Vorläufer von Lassie). Das Stück war in Paris ein großer Erfolg, ebenso in London. Im September 1815 sorgte die deutsche Übersetzung in Wien für Furore, ab Oktober 1815 auch in Berlin.

Zwei Jahre danach, 1817, schlug die Schauspielerin Caroline Jagemann dem Großherzog Carl August von Sachsen-Weimar-Eisenach vor, dieses Stück auch in Weimar aufzuführen. Carl August war nicht nur ein großer Hundefreund, sondern hatte auch seit Jahren immer wieder Streit mit Goethe. Und so befahl der Großherzog das Hunde-Stück an Goethes Theater aufführen zu lassen. Die Rolle des Hundes sollte der dressierte Pudel Nero spielen, der dem Schauspieler Rudolf Karsten gehörte.

Goethe drohte dem Fürsten gegenüber mit dem Abschied von dem Theater (also quasi »Der Pudel oder ich«). Der Landesfürst nahm Goethes Abschied sofort an. 1817 verließ Goethe das Theater und ein Pudel trat auf die Bühne.

(Aber das passierte, wie gesagt, erst nachdem Faust I veröffentlicht wurde. Diese Geschichte war also nicht der Anlass für den Pudel in Goethes Werk, aber sehr bezeichnend für Goethes Verhältnis zu Pudeln.)

Comment: Goethe wird mir immer sympathischer. :)

Answer (score -1):

Ich glaube auch nicht, dass die Redefigur *Pudels Kern* von Goethe ist.

Wie kommt der Dichter darauf, einen Hund (oder eine Kaufmannstheke?) mit einem *Kern* zu verbinden? Damals werden *Kerne* Obstkerne gewesen sein? (*Atomkerne* waren unbekannt, sie wurden überhaupt erst im 20. Jhd. postuliert.)

Ich finde die Kombination *Pudels Kern* viel zu ungewöhnlich dafür, dass es für damalige Zuschauer keinen mitgedachten historischen Hintergrund gegeben hätte. Und selbst in heutigen Ohren wirkt *Pudels Kern* noch leicht sperrig.

Ehrlich gesagt, mir ist die hier angebotene Herleitung aus den Vorfällen am Theater in Weimar etwas zu platt. Das passt überhaupt nicht dazu, dass die ganze metaphysische Teufelei in einem Pudelkern verborgen sein könnte.

Comment: Den *Faust* gelesen hast du aber schon?